# Retrieving the sum of items of a particular type from a collection in a RavenDB Index

Tags: .net, mapreduce, ravendb

I am trying to create an index with a similar class and index definitions to that shown below:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Bar
{
    public int Weight { get; set; }
}

public class IronBar : Bar { }

public class ChocolateBar : Bar { }

public class TagSummary
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int TotalChocolateBarWeight { get; set; }
    public int TotalIronBarWeight { get; set; }
}

public class TagSummaryIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Foo, TagSummary>
{
    public TagSummaryIndex()
    {
        Map = foos => from f in foos
                      select new
                      {
                          Tag = f.Tag,
                          Count = 1,
                          TotalChocolateBarWeight = f.Bars.OfType<ChocolateBar>().Sum(x=> x.Weight),
                          TotalIronBarWeight = f.Bars.OfType<IronBar>().Sum(x=> x.Weight)
                      };

        Reduce = results => from r in results
                            group r by r.Tag into g
                            select new
                            {
                                Tag = g.Key,
                                Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count),
                                TotalChocolateBarWeight = g.Sum(x => x.TotalChocolateBarWeight),
                                TotalIronBarWeight = g.Sum(x => x.TotalIronBarWeight)
                            };
    }
}
```

However when I try to create the indexes

```
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(this.GetType().Assembly, _documentStore);
```

it throws an InvalidOperationException.  If I remove the `.OfType<T>()` parts from `Map`  then all is fine (but not what I want).  I've tried using `Where(x => x is ChocolateBar)` and various other type checking options but to no avail.

How would I go about achieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing you could do is to add some properties to your class that precalculate the subtotals.

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
    public int ChocolateBarsWeight
    {
        get
        {
            return Bars.OfType<ChocolateBar>().Sum(x => x.Weight);
        }
    }
    public int IronBarsWeight
    {
        get
        {
            return Bars.OfType<IronBar>().Sum(x => x.Weight);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use those values in your index map:

```
TotalChocolateBarWeight = f.ChocolateBarsWeight,
TotalIronBarWeight = f.IronBarsWeight
```

However, I'm tending to agree that `.OfType<T>()` should work in this case, and it doesn't.  Reason being is that the type information is serialized for each bar as a `$type` value in the json. This happens any time you store an abstract base type or an interface.  For example:

```
{
    "Tag": "A",
    "Bars": [
        {
            "$type": "YourNameSpace.ChocolateBar, YourNameSpace",
            "Weight": 10
        },
        {
            "$type": "YourNameSpace.IronBar, YourNameSpace",
            "Weight": 1000
        }
    ]
}
```

Raven should be able to pick up on this and properly handle `.OfType<T>()`.  I will suggest it for their next major release.

Comment: Thanks Matt, yep, that would be a handy feature for me. I'll precalculate them for the time being.